# Subplot from already created plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have a function which returns a plot for specific column

```
def class_distribution(colname):
    df = tweets_best.groupby(["HandLabel", colname]).size().to_frame("size")
    df['percentage'] = df.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: (x / x.sum()).round(2))
    df_toPlot = df[["percentage"]]
    
    plot = df_toPlot.unstack().plot.bar()
    plt.legend(df_toPlot.index.get_level_values(level = 1))
    plt.title("{} predicted sentiment distribution".format(colname))
    plt.ylim((0,1))
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
    return plot.get_figure()
```

And example output looks like this

```
nb = class_distribution("Naive_Bayes")
```

[image: example_output]

I would like to produce 4 plots like this and present them as subplots 2 rows and 2 columns. However if i try

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
nb
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
sn
```

I get

[image: example_output2]

which is obviously not something I would expect

Comment: The code is still a bit too complex for the presented error. Maybe make it shorter and in line with a [example].

Comment: The code is not really so complex. It is all about that the function creates and returns a barplot such as the one presented at the example image. Now the thing is to use this function to create subplots. Instead of 

`plt.subplot(1,2,1) \n  plt.bar(x,y)`

use this:

`plt.subplot(1,2,1) \n class_distribution(colname)`

Comment: If you want four plots you should use `plt.subplot(2, 2, ...)`. Then after selecting one of the subplots via `plt.subplot(2, 2, i)` where `i = (1, 2, 3, 4)` you need to plot whatever you want to plot.

Comment: It does not work. I get exactly the same output as in the case of the code with `plt.subplot(1,2,i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to plot **to** an already existing axes. So your function should take an axes as input:

```
def class_distribution(colname, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()

    df = ...  # create dataframe based on function input

    df.unstack().plot.bar(ax=ax)
    ax.legend(...)
    ax.set_title("{} predicted sentiment distribution".format(colname))
    ax.set_ylim((0,1))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
    return ax
```

Then, you can create a figure and one or several subplots to plot to:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
class_distribution("colname1", ax=ax1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
class_distribution("colname2", ax=ax2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your output is exactly what you'd expect given your code:

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
nb
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
sn
```

In this line `plt.subplot(1,2,1)` you're specifying two plots in this arrangement: one row and two columns, and placing the plot on the left.

The `(1,2,1)` specifies (number of rows, number of columns, index to plot).

Since you want subplots arranged 2 by 2, specify `(2,2,i)` where `i` is the index.  This will arrange your plots:

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
{plot in upper left}
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
{plot in upper right}
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
{plot in lower left}
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
{plot in lower right}
```

Additionally, you can handle axes as ImportanceOfBeingEarnest details.  You can also `share axes` and make use of several other parameters and arguments:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

A minimal working example will better identify the problem and get better answers.